# R: How to produce file names with `write` depending on given parameters

Tags: r, csv

in R I collect `n^2` numerical matrices, each matrix depending on a pair of numerical parameters `a`, `b`.
I would like to write each matrix `M` in a separate file, specifying in the file name the pair `a`, `b`. I am thinking about

```
write.csv(M,file="M_0_0")
```

for `a==0` `b==0` and so on.

Unfortunately I do not know how to automate the process and arrive at the  collection "M_a_b"; have you any suggestion regarding the necessary syntax?

I thank you very much!

Comment: `?paste` and a for-loop might be handy here....

Comment: You can also look at `sprintf`.

Comment: I see: file=paste(...) is what you are referring to, EDi?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As EDi suggested,

```
for (j in 1:n) {
for (k in 1:n){
    # create or rename your matrix here
    write.csv(M, file= paste("M_",j,"_",k,sep='',collapse=''))
}
}
```

But unless there's some disastrously bad code elsewhere which insists on having one matrix per file, I'd strongly recommend storing your matrices in as few files as possible, indexed in some sensible way.

Comment: Thank you! The "here's some disastrously bad code" passage made me smirk, because it is probably the case eheh.